# Text versioning in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-design

I'm developing a little blog-like web application (with java+mysql), and I'm thinking about the db design.
In my application, each article is made of subsection (from 1 to n), and each edit to a single section have to be saved in the database.
What is the best way to design the article tables? I was thinking of dynamically creating from java a table for each new section. It is the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to dynamically create a new table for each new section. See if the following gets your creative juices flowing:

**Table List**

- article : holds a list of all articles
- section : holds a list of all
  sections including to which article they belong
- sectionEdit : holds a
  list of edits to sections including to which section the edit was
  made

Though it kinda depends on exactly what information you want to include in each section. If the sections all have the same structure/attributes then the above should work.